# Help wiring bathroom fan!

Tags: bathroom

[image][image]

I am having trouble wiring wiring this Nutone roomside dc series 110 vent fan! Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: We need to know what "1" "2" and "3" are in the ceiling. I presume a fan was already there? Can you tell us precisely what 1 2 3 were connected to or if each has HOT and NEUTRAL on each?

Comment: They are each a set of black and white wires with a bare ground wire

Comment: Added new picture for clarification

Comment: Yellow marker indicates white wire

Comment: We really need to know either a.) Precisely how they were connected to whatever they were connected to (wirenuts and all) (or) b.) what each one is doing or will do. Example...one or all of them may be HOT to the panel (probably not), or, all three are coming from three different switches, or two come from switches, one is hot, or one gives power to a light.... ETC.  Do you have a Meter/Tester and are you comfortable testing it? If not, you should call a pro.

Comment: There are three switches in the bathroom

Comment: They each control one switch

Comment: Switch one is outside the bathroom door, two and three are inside the bathroom.

Comment: Did you remove what was there previously, if so, tell us what it was? and do you have any pictures of the wiring before you removed it? You are confident that all three switches you mention controlled three different things? And again, please answer whether you have a tester/meter. (PS: just answer in one comment, no need to create different ones for separate sentences), thanks!

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the boxes involved?

Comment: Real pictures is needed, but it should have been a two way light with a fan switch on the inside. Take apart the wall switches too, and pull out the switches (but don't disconnect them) and snap pictures.